# C# Event Handler for a Timer Object

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

What I need is to have a timer fire an event handler (say every second) which
is in another class. This will be a small part of a Windows form program.

I have tried using a delegate to "call" an event handler, but I keep getting
syntax errors. Can somebody steer me in the correct direction with a simple
code example?

The code below is my start, the commented portion works fine but I want the
event to fire when a Windows timer fires.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event TimerHandler Tick;
        public EventArgs e = null;
        public delegate void TimerHandler(Timer t, EventArgs e);

        public class Timer
        {
            public event TimerHandler Tick;
            public EventArgs e = null;
            public delegate void TimerHandler(Timer t, EventArgs e);
        }

        public class Listener
        {
            public static int ticker = 0;
            public void Subscribe(Timer t)
            {
                t.Tick += new Timer.TimerHandler(HeardTick);
            }
            private void HeardTick(Timer t, EventArgs e)
            {
                //lblTimer.Text = ticker.ToString(); //Don't know how to change forms control
                ticker++;
            }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer();
            Listener l = new Listener();
            l.Subscribe(t);
            //t.Start();
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Tick != null)
            {
                Tick(this, e); // "this" is incorrect, invalid argument
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your code!We would help you correct it..

Comment: **Close-Voting:** *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: Perhaps give the newbie a chance to edit his question before closing? :)

Comment: Remember when asking questions to specify [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). This will help you get the answers you need.

Comment: @JunWeiLee The point of closing a question is to give the author time to edit the question; if they are able to improve it then it can be reopened without the answer being harmed by low quality answers posted before it was in an answerable state.  Leaving a question open when it's not ready to be answers is more harmful to the author than closing it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Is the other class static?
Here is an example for each:

```
//Static class
Timer1.Tick += YourClass.DoStuff;

//Non-static class
YourClass MyInstance = new YourClass();
Timer1.Tick += MyInstance.DoStuff;
```

Just put the code in the constructor of your form.